# Import error in android studio design and v7 - Android Studio -

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to java and Android studio, but I tried to create an app

Here is the code -

```
MainActivity.java

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

In this code, the design word shows - cannot resolve symbol 'design'

and, the v7 word shows - cannot resolve symbol 'v7'

```
build.gradle(Module:app)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

If, I ran this program which shows compiler error

```
error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
```

How to resolve this error, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **androidx** implementations, you should use

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
```

But if you want to run with your imports,
compile this dependencies in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is rather simple. You are using different import libraries than the one you currently have in you project dependencies.

In your case you are importing `android.support` [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) but your gradle dependencies shows you have included the following libraries instead

- `androidx` ( [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) )
- `com.google.android.material` ( [Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) )

[AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) is the newer, better and preferred version of the previous support library since the release of Android Pie (API 28). [Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) are google's official implementation of there material design widgets including `FloatingActionButton` , `BottomAppBar` etc.

Since you are new I'm assuming it doesn't matter whether you use `androidx` or `android.support`. For now just use AndroidX. So just import the correct libraries as follows

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have migrated to AndroidX. Remove those three imports

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

and add this

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `androidx` which is part of android `jetpack` So that it's not support `support design import` You can solve this problem simply just change the import to

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Hope it's work nicely. 
Also you can learn about jetpack androidx from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

Answer (score 1):

This will cause for you have use androidx For development so design library is deprecated use..

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

this material library created by google for all View and widgets..
hope it will help you..